# Mouseclick event inside mouseclick event works with IE and other browsers, not with firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Please see below code... Aims of the code is to display a floating menu on right clicking the screen and the menu should hide on left clicking the screen. The below works perfectly with IE and Chrome, but fails in firefox. I tried debugging with firebug, no positives at all.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.onmousedown = onMouseClick;
}

function onMouseDown(ev) {

    document.oncontextmenu = onClickRightMouseButton; //to hide default menu on right click

    if (ev.which == 1) {
        console.log('1');
    }

    if (ev.which == 2) {
        console.log('2');
    }

    if (ev.which == 3) {
        var xPos = ev.clientX;
        var yPos = ev.clientY;

        document.onmousedown = onMouseClick;
        showFloatingMenu(xPos, yPos);
    }

    function onMouseClick(e) {
        if (e.which == 1) {
            if (!(e.clientX >= xPos && e.clientX <= (xPos + 200) && e.clientY >= yPos && e.clientY <= (yPos + 50))) { //50x200 is the floating menu diamension
                hideFloatingMenu();
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Why do you not set the oncontextmenu until after a click? And where are onMouseClick and onClickRightMouseButton? You tagged this jQuery, where is the jQuery?

Comment: When do you assign onMouseDown? I see `document.onmousedown = onMouseClick` and I see `function onMouseDown(ev)`

Comment: @mplungjan I am planning to add few options like add/delete on the context menu on right click. Once left mouse button is clicked (out side menu), it should hide. I'm using onmousedown instead on onmouseclick.. Does that having any issues? I am using jquery to attach the onMouseClick event to document on loading. Btw.. I am new to UI programming, these cross browser thinks looks confusing..

Comment: @mplungjan There are two onMouseClick functions, one inside onMouseDown and and other outside, this stuff works perfectly with IE and Chrome!

Comment: Be consistent and use jQuery's normalising of events so `$(document).on("mousedown",function(e) {...})` and so on. Also install firebug and hit F12 perhaps there are errors in the console

Comment: @mplungjan tried with firebug, onMouseClick function inside onMouseDown never invoked. I am wondering why it is working on IE and Chrome. Can you please explain with an example on handling this situation using jquery (I'm very new to UI development)